# Python: TypeError: 'Image' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

tengo un error que no sé como solucionar:

> TypeError: 'Image' object does not support item assignment.

Lo que hago es convertir un punto rgb a cmyk -> punto a un cuadrícula de 3*3 (la imagen resultante será más grande), estos puntos de la cuadrícula serán magenta, cyan, yellow, black en proporción a la cantidad de color que haya dado la conversión. No soy programador profesional, solo un gran aficionado interesado en la programación. Así que posiblemente este programa se podría mejorar totalmente, cualquier sugerencia se agradece.

`````
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageColor
import cv2
import numpy as np
imagen = Image.open("tintin.jpg")#primero pasamos a RGB
rgb_imagen = imagen.convert('RGB')
width, height = rgb_imagen.size
imagen2 = Image.new("RGB", (width*3, height*3), (255,255,255,255))
matriz = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
m = np.array(matriz)
y=1
while ( y<(height-1) ):
    x=1
    while ( x<(width-2)):
       r, g, b = rgb_imagen.getpixel((x, y)) 
       k = 1.0000001-(max(r,g,b)/255)
       cyan = (1-r/255-k)/(1-k)
       magenta = (1-g/255-k)/(1-k)
       yellow = (1-b/255-k)/(1-k)
       k1=100*round(k, 2)
       cyan1=100*round(cyan, 2)
       magenta1=100*round(magenta,2)
       yellow1=100*round(yellow,2)
       total= (k1+cyan1+magenta1+yellow1)+0.0000001
       k2= (k1/total)*100
       cyan2= (cyan1/total)*100
       magenta2= (magenta1/total)*100
       yellow2= (yellow1/total)*100
       k3=round(k2,0)
       cyan3=round(cyan2,0)
       magenta3=round(magenta2,0)
       yellow3=round(yellow2,0)
       k4=(int)(round((k3*9/100),0))
       cyan4=(int)(round((cyan3*9/100),0))
       magenta4=(int)(round((magenta3*9/100),0))
       yellow4=(int)(round((yellow3*9/100),0))
       print("cyan%=",cyan4,"magenta%=",magenta4,"yellow%=",yellow4,"negro=%",k4)
       i=0
       while (i!=9):
             if (cyan4!=0):
                m[i]= [0,255,255]; cyan4=cyan4-1; i=i+1
             if (magenta4!=0):
                m[i]= [255,0,255]; magenta4=magenta4-1; i=i+1
             if (yellow4!=0):
                m[i]= [255,255,0]; yellow4=yellow4-1; i=i+1
             if (k4!=0):
                m[i]= [0,0,0]; k4=k4-1; i=i+1 
       print (m)        

       imagen2[x-1, y-1]=  m[1]                                       
       imagen2[x, y-1]=  m[2] 
       imagen2[x+1, y-1]= m[3]  
       imagen2[x-1, y]=  m[4] 
       imagen2[x+1,y]= m[5]   
       imagen2[x, y]=  m[6] 
       imagen2[x-1, y+1]=  m[7]   
       imagen2[x, y+1]=  m[8] 
       imagen2[x+1, y+1]=  m[9]  
       x=x+1
    y=y+1    

imagen2.save("cmyk_aprox.gif") ````
`````

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta es

```
imagen2.putpixel((x-1, y-1), m[1])
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero sigo sin solucionar el problema, cambiando el código a image2.putpixel.... ahora sale : SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

Comment: trata `imagen2.putpixel((x-1, y-1), tuple(m[1]))`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora funciona. A parte de esto, sigo sin conseguir que imprima lo que quiero (pero ese es otro tema).

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageColor
import numpy as np
imagen = Image.open("bs.gif")#primero pasamos a RGB
rgb_imagen = imagen.convert('RGB')
width, height = rgb_imagen.size
imagen2 = Image.new("RGB", (width*3, height*3), (255,255,255,255))
matriz = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
m = np.array(matriz)
y=1; control = 0
while ( y<((height)-1) ):
    #print(control,"----------------------------------------------")
    control=control+1
    x=1
    while ( x<((width)-1)):
       r, g, b = rgb_imagen.getpixel((x, y)) 
       k = 1.0000001-(max(r,g,b)/255)
       cyan = (1-r/255-k)/(1-k)
       magenta = (1-g/255-k)/(1-k)
       yellow = (1-b/255-k)/(1-k)
       k1=100*round(k, 2)
       cyan1=100*round(cyan, 2)
       magenta1=100*round(magenta,2)
       yellow1=100*round(yellow,2)
       total= (k1+cyan1+magenta1+yellow1)+0.0000001
       k2= (k1/total)*100
       cyan2= (cyan1/total)*100
       magenta2= (magenta1/total)*100
       yellow2= (yellow1/total)*100
       k3=round(k2,0)
       cyan3=round(cyan2,0)
       magenta3=round(magenta2,0)
       yellow3=round(yellow2,0)
       k4=(int)(round((k3*9/100),0))
       cyan4=(int)(round((cyan3*9/100),0))
       magenta4=(int)(round((magenta3*9/100),0))
       yellow4=(int)(round((yellow3*9/100),0))
       print("cyan%=",cyan4,"magenta%=",magenta4,"yellow%=",yellow4,"negro=%",k4)
       i=0
       while (i<9):
             if (cyan4!=0):
                m[i]= [0,255,255]; cyan4=cyan4-1; i=i+1
             if (magenta4!=0):
                m[i]= [255,0,255]; magenta4=magenta4-1; i=i+1
             if (yellow4!=0):
                m[i]= [255,255,0]; yellow4=yellow4-1; i=i+1
             if (k4!=0):
                m[i]= [0,0,0]; k4=k4-1; i=i+1
             if (cyan4==0 and magenta4==0 and yellow4==0 and k4==0):
                i=i+1
       input("Presione una tecla para continuar...")
       print (m); print (x,y)      
       imagen2.putpixel(((x-1)*3, (y-1)*3), tuple(m[0]))                                       
       imagen2.putpixel(((x)*3, (y-1)*3) ,tuple(m[1]),) 
       imagen2.putpixel(((x+1)+3, (y-1)*3), tuple(m[2])) 
       imagen2.putpixel(((x-1)*3, (y)*3), tuple(m[3])) 
       imagen2.putpixel(((x+1)*3,(y)*3), tuple(m[4])) 
       imagen2.putpixel(((x)*3,(y)*3), tuple(m[5]))
       imagen2.putpixel(((x-1)*3, (y+1)*3), tuple(m[6]))  
       imagen2.putpixel(((x)*3, (y+1)*3), tuple(m[7]))
       imagen2.putpixel(((x+1)*3, (y+1)*3), tuple(m[8])) 
       x=x+1
    y=y+1   

imagen2.save("cmyk_aprox.gif")
```

Esto he conseguido hasta ahora, pero estoy haciendo algo mal, la imagen saliente tendría que ser cmyk (proporción colores a la conversión) y cuadrículas 3x3 hasta completar la imagen, si alguien está interesado en el tema acepto sugerencias, gracias.